# Add file.Name, file.CreationTime in another columns using ListView with foreach in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, foreach, fileinfo

I have checked other solutions, but I just can't get it to work!

```
   DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@leftComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "");
        FileInfo[] files= d.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            //leftListView.Items.Add(file.Name + " [" + file.CreationTime + "] ");
            var item1 = new ListViewItem(file.Name, file.CreationTime);


        }
```

Im kinda lost.

```
      <ListView Name="leftListView" AlternationCount="2"
 Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                 SelectionChanged="leftListView_SelectionChanged"  />
```

Comment: You're doing this the hard way.  Start learning MVVM.  Build some simple prototypes.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML file

```
<ListView Name="leftListView" AlternationCount="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CreationTime}" />                        
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In your code .cs file

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Documents\Company");
        FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.*");
        leftListView.ItemsSource = files;
```

Comment: Do I need to bind something in XAML part?

Comment: Oh, okay! I need help with WPF :)

Comment: Updated the answer for WPF. Misunderstood it the first time around